# Create a bookmarklet that runs this when clicked `:screenshot --selector "[node]"` (Firefox)

Tags: firefox, screenshot, mozilla, bookmarklet

Is it possible to create a bookmarklet that I could have as a button to press when ever I need to have a screenshot from a specific node in a website?

In [Starcraft 2 Wiki](https://liquipedia.net/starcraft2/Main_Page) I would like a screenshot of their tournament list node `.tournaments-list`. I can use Web Console to do that by typing:
`:screenshot --selector ".tournaments-list"`

I basically just want to make this whole task easy to use. So if you have any suggestions on any other method that I could do this like creating an extension or making a macro perhaps please let me know.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is exactly what you need, but on any bookmarklet, you can type Javascript code instead of the URL. For example, you can [use this converter](https://mrcoles.com/bookmarklet/) to convert js to "bookmarletish"

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have tried to search for JavaScript code witch would enable you to do the same as the Web Console command `:screenshot`, but I haven't had any luck with that.

I think I would able to do this easily if I could write JavaScript to send that `:screenshot` command to the Web Console directly. At the moment I haven't found a solution to that.